# Get information from external url and put it on my own website

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to get the results from this page, [IEEExplore](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/gateway/ipsSearch.jsp?querytext=java&au=Wang&hc=10&rs=11&sortfield=ti&sortorder=asc), and extract information so I can display certain information on my own webpage. Is there a possibility in Jquery or javascript? Can i get the information in a JSON format or is that not the way to do it?

I was thinking of something like this:

```
 $.get(url,function( data ) { 
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data.result );
 });
```

With url being the IEEExplore url.

Comment: same origin policy will prevent that unless the site allows jsonp, using an xml parser on the server would be the way to go

Comment: Ok i get the same origin policy, so how can i see if a site allows jsonp?

Comment: It'd be much easier to do this serverside in the long run, useful info here if you're using php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: can also use third party proxy service like Yahoo YQL to transform the xml to json. Quick and easy to set up in their sandbox console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site in question will either have to support [JSONP](http://json-p.org/) or you'll have to load/proxy the data on your server. Then you can just load it as you've suggested, create a DOM tree from the loaded XML using `$(loadedXml)` and use the plethora of jQuery functions at your disposal to find/process any of the contained data.

Comment: where can I find some more information about load/proxy data on my server?

Comment: Try [Google](https://www.google.com/). There's a million ways to do this, one example would be using [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) if you're running an Apache web-server.